# how to send query parameters from material dialog box in front to node js back-end

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-material

i'm beginner in angular and node i have a material datatable by this code:

```
<!-- Action Column -->
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="action"  style="width: 30%;">
                      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > action </th>
                      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let list_product"> 
                        <button mat-icon-button color="accent" color="primary" (click)="openDialog('Update',list_product)">
                          <mat-icon aria-label="Example icon-button with a heart icon"> EDIT </mat-icon>
                        </button>


                        <button mat-icon-button color="accent" (click)="openDialog('Delete',list_product)">
                          <mat-icon aria-label="Example icon-button with a heart icon"> DELETE </mat-icon>
                        </button>
   
                      </td>
                    </ng-container>
```

list_product is my datasource from backend

for openDialog i have this code :

```
 openDialog(action,obj) {
    obj.action = action;
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogBoxComponent, {
      width: '250px',
      data:obj
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      if(result.event == 'Add'){
        this.addRowData(result.data);
      }else if(result.event == 'Update'){
        this.updateRowData(result.data);
      }else if(result.event == 'Delete'){
        this.deleteRowData(result.data);
      }
    });
```

deleteRowData is code below:

```
deleteRowData(row_obj){
      // this.dataSource.data = this.dataSource.data.filter((value,key)=>{
      // console.log(row_obj);
      const idno=row_obj.id;
       console.log("idno is :" + row_obj.id);
      this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/item_delete",{params: {idno}}).subscribe(
           () => {}
      );
      // return value.id != row_obj.id;
```

}

back-end code :

```
app.post("/item_delete",(req,res)=>{
    
    console.log('id number is :' + req.body.idno);
    const deletequery="DELETE * FROM captiontbl WHERE id='" + req.body.idno + "')";
    console.log(deletequery);
    ConnectToDB().query(deletequery,(err,result)=>{

       if (err){
           console.log("error"+err);
           res.sendStatus(500); 
           return;
       }
       res.send("deleted" + result);
       console.log("record deleted");
       res.end();
   })
});
```

problem :
in deleteRowData(row_obj) in ts file the value of row_obj.id is true and sended to back-end but in back-end req.body.idno return **undefined** value and Delete query not work

Answer (score 0):

You're sending  `{ params: {idno: idno } }`

then you will get in the backend server:  req.body.params and there is nothing to do with `fields`.

please update your backend code to:

```
console.log('id number is :' + req.body.idno);
```

then will you know what you receive and adjust your code in according.

btw you can shorthand `{idno:idno}` to `{idno}` // Shorthand property names (ES2015)